# Combining variables in spss python

Tags: python, spss

I am working with a large data set in SPSS. One variable represents students' first major and has values 1-15 referring to 15 different types of majors students can have.  A second variable is the same but for second/double majors.

I want to combine the responses into one single variable major group.

I got it to work this way:

```
do if(major1Group =1 or major2Group=1).
compute majorGroup = 1. 
ELSE IF(major1Group = 2 or major2Group = 2).
compute majorGroup = 2. 
else if(major1Group =3 or major2Group=3). 
compute majorGroup = 3. 
else if(major1Group =4 or major2Group=4).
compute majorGroup = 4. 
else if(major1Group =5 or major2Group=5).
compute majorGroup = 5. 
else if(major1Group =6 or major2Group=6).
compute majorGroup = 6. 
else if(major1Group =7 or major2Group=7).
compute majorGroup = 7. 
else if(major1Group =8 or major2Group=8).
compute majorGroup = 8. 
else if(major1Group =9 or major2Group=9).
compute majorGroup = 9. 
else if(major1Group =10 or major2Group=10).
compute majorGroup = 10. 
else if(major1Group =11 or major2Group=11).
compute majorGroup = 11. 
else if(major1Group =12 or major2Group=12).
compute majorGroup = 12. 
ELSE if(major1Group =13 or major2Group=13).
compute majorGroup = 13. 
else if(major1Group =14 or major2Group=14).
compute majorGroup = 14. 
else if(major1Group =15 or major2Group=15).
compute majorGroup = 15.  
end if.
```

... but I am sure that there must be a more efficient way for the future. My attempt:

```
    begin program.
    import spss,spssaux
    vdict = spssaux.VariableDict
    major1Group = vdict("major1Group")
    major2Group = vdict("major2Group")
    iterations = len(major1Group)
    i = 1 
    majorGroup = []
    while i <= iterations: 
       if ((major1Group == i) or (major2Group == i)):
          majorGroup[i] = i
       i = i+1

    end program.
```

Thank you so much. I am relatively new to both SPSS and python so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Before attempting to streamline your code, your logic in the code as it is is, or at least to me seem to be, very ambiguous. As you have it the tail end of course codes will have less and less of a probability of being captured in your target variable as it may be present with earlier codes. Hope the point I'm trying to make resonates with you.. perhaps you could clarify your objectives here.

Answer (score 2):

You will get the same result (refering to the spss syntax code) with just one line of code:

```
COMPUTE majorGroup = MIN(major1Group, major2Group).
```